# Get Session from HttpRequestContext in Jersey

Tags: java, session, servlets, jersey, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard and wrote a Security Provider that should check the session. If a user is available, it should return it. Otherwise it should throw an exception. How can I get the Session from an HttpRequestContext?

```
public class SecurityProvider<T> implements InjectableProvider<Auth, Parameter> {

  private static class Injectable<T> extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<T> {

    @Override
    public T getValue(HttpContext c) {
     //Here, get somehow the session,
     //then check if user is in session,
     //if so, proceed

     return null;
    }
  }

 @Override
 public ComponentScope getScope() {
    return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
 }

 @Override
 public com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Auth auth, Parameter parameter) {
   return new Injectable<T>();
 }
}
```